# Fill-up Array in passed in JNI Method call

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have a empty array initialised in java code. Now I'm passing that array in JNI method call.
Now, what i want is to fill-up array with N number of elements.

When call returns to java the array object passed in method remains empty.

Here is my code

**Java**

```
MyClass[] array = new MyClass[]{};
nativeLib.fillupArray(array);
```

**Native**

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_com_example_jniexample_fillupArray(JNIEnv *env, jclass jniexampleClass, jobjectArray array){
jclass clazz = (*env).FindClass("com/example/jniexample$MyClass");
jmethodID constructor = (*env).GetMethodID(clazz,"<init>" ,"()V");

    jfieldID srNo = (*env).GetFieldID(clazz, "srNo", "I");
    jfieldID name = (*env).GetFieldID(clazz, "name", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    
    array = (*env).NewObjectArray(N, clazz, NULL);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        jobject obj = (*env).NewObject(clazz, constructor);
    
        jobject p = (jobject) "Person";
        
        (*env).SetIntField(obj, srNo, i);
        (*env).SetObjectField(obj, name, p);
    
        (*env).SetObjectArrayElement(array, i, obj);
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you're creating the string object in a weird way. It should rather be something like `jobject p = env->NewStringUTF("Person")`. Also, you need to remove the line `array = (*env).NewObjectArray(N, clazz, NULL);` as this will create a new array instead of modifying the old one.

Comment: You can't resize Java arrays. Pass an array of the correct size (and remove the `NewObjectArray` call). If you don't know the size beforehand, use something like an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Or just have the native function create and return an array instead of modifying an existing one.

Comment: @Michael first of all i have 2 fields that want back in java 1.status 2.array. now as you said if i change return type to array then still problem remains same I'm not able get updated status back in java if status field is passed in method call. So, i must have to update object array in jni and return status.

Comment: @LorenzHetterich i have n number of elements to be filled in array so i have to somehow reinitiate array with new size. But I don't know how. And that string object creation is just a example to describe what i want. 

Comment: if you want to create a new array, you must return that array. there is no (intended and portable) way to change the size of an already existing array.